# Interpretation of negative value in varImp() of Random Forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am using `randomForest()` function from package randomForest. I am trying the understand the output given by the function `varImp()` of package caret. For few variables it is showing negative values. What does negative value indicate?

Below is the output:

```
           Overall
Year        6.7712260
Month      -2.6684553
DOW         2.2681865
City.Group -0.3534247
Type        1.4049568
P1          8.5207072
P2          6.0449333
P3          5.3579060
P4          4.1441309
P5          5.9207454
P6          7.3744485
P7          3.6858546
```

Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918320/what-does-negative-incmse-in-randomforest-package-mean/27920414#27920414)